# Unnecessary symbols in URL Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url

Hello. I have a WordPress website.

I have a trouble.When I adding symbols in my URL, server gives the status 200 ok.

**Example** - mysite.com/page/

I have a page like this.

I can add symbols "---" or "123" to the end of URL, something like this
mysite.com/page/**123** or mysite.com/**----------page-----**/ or mysite.com/category/**123**/page
AND server respond with status 200 OK, ibutI need that mysite.com/**--page--**/ redirect to the mysite.com/page.And also with other symbols.
Is there a solution to this problem? May be plugin or regex expression?

home-service.com.ua/kontakty/

home-service.com.ua/------------kontakty------/

home-service.com.ua/kontakty/123/

It's all one page. I need to remove all these characters ("----","123").
Redirect from this pages to the original home-service.com.ua/kontakty/

Comment: Could you bring an example to a URL you want to change? The question is not clear enough

Comment: And what is the original URL?

Comment: I update the question

Answer (score 0):

[WordPress redirect plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) allows you to redirect a specific URL to a different URL, and has options to redirect with regex rules .

Comment: I have a lot of pages. About 300 pages.

Comment: Is there a common "rule" to all redirections? The examples you brought seems like to be different from each other

Comment: yes, this is for all redirections... i see this is a standart problem of all wordpress website. On each website i can add a "---" or "/0/" in URL and its work.

Comment: Can you give me 3 examples links "before" and "after". and examples to a other site that same page loaded for 3 different links

Comment: www.angrybirds.com/-------------------games-------------/
www.angrybirds.com/characters/123/

thewaltdisneycompany.com/---environment--------------/
thewaltdisneycompany.com/news/123/

Comment: angry bird and walt disney company

Comment: @TheRock you could create the CSV file with a simple php loop